# Obtener Horarios Disponible mendiante 2 Array, 1 Array Traer las Horas (H:i) Inciales y/o Finales de la base de datos y el otro traer los horarios dis

Tags: php, sql, array, json

Buenas Tardes intenta generar array dónde soo me coloque los horarios disponible en base la información que este guarda en mi tabla de cita.

Genero un Array dónde guardar la horas iniciales de la base de datos, si me recomienda cambiar por la hora finale, estoy dispuesto a realizar dicho cambi.

Tengo otro Array que obtengo los horarios fraccionario por intervalo de tiempo, en base a una cabina que contenga hora de comida.

El objetivo es realizar una cita cuando hay cita registrar y pueda cubrir los minutos de cada una.

adjunto código PHP, solo es código PHP., se manda por medio de un array.

```
<?php  
    require('../php/connect.php');

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
    $hora = date('H:i:s');

    // $idCabina = $_POST['idCabina'];
    // $sucursal = $_POST['sucursal'];
    // $totalTiempo = $_POST['timeTotal'];
    // $fechaCita = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['fechaCita']));
    //$fechaCita = $_POST['fechaCita'];
    

    $idCabina = 2;
    $sucursal = 2;
    $totalTiempo = 35;
    $fechaCita = '2022-12-02';
    // $fechaCita = '13-11-2022';
    

    $horasFiltradas = array();
    $horasAlm = array();
    $select = array();
    $horasFiltradasM = array();
    $minutos = array();

    $selectCitas = $con->query("SELECT * FROM citas WHERE status = 1 AND fechaCita = '$fechaCita' AND sucursal = '$sucursal' AND numCabi = '$idCabina'");
    if($selectCitas->num_rows > 0){

        $ide = 'Hay Citas';

        while ($rowCitas = $selectCitas->fetch_assoc()) {

            $horaIniCita = $rowCitas['horaCita'];
            $horaFinCita = $rowCitas['horaFinCita'];

            array_push($select, date("H", strtotime($horaIniCita)));
            array_push($minutos, date("H:i", strtotime($horaIniCita)));
            
        }

        $selectCabinis = $con->query("SELECT * FROM cabinas WHERE id = '$idCabina' AND sucursal = '$sucursal' AND status = 1");
        $rowCabinis = $selectCabinis->fetch_assoc();

        if($rowCabinis['tieneComida'] == 1){

            $intervarlo = '+'.$totalTiempo.'minutes';
            $intervarlo2 = 'PT'.$totalTiempo.'M';
            
            $inicio = new DateTime($rowCabinis['horaIni']);
            if($totalTiempo > 60){
                $menosunoho1 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-2 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaComidaIni'])));
            }else{
                $menosunoho1 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-1 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaComidaIni'])));
            }
            $inicioComida = new DateTime($menosunoho1);
            $inicioComida = $inicioComida->modify($intervarlo);

            $rangoFechas = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval($intervarlo2), $inicioComida);
            foreach($rangoFechas as $fecha){
                array_push($horasAlm,$fecha->format("H:i"));
            }

            $finComida = new DateTime($rowCabinis['horaComidaFin']);
            if($totalTiempo > 60){
                $menosunoho2 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-2 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaFin'])));
            }else{
                $menosunoho2 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-1 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaFin'])));
            }
            $fin = new DateTime($menosunoho2);
            $fin = $fin->modify($intervarlo);

            $rangoFechas2 = new DatePeriod($finComida, new DateInterval($intervarlo2), $fin);
            foreach($rangoFechas2 as $fecha2){
                array_push($horasAlm,$fecha2->format("H:i"));
            }

        }else{

            $intervarlo = '+'.$totalTiempo.'minutes';
            $intervarlo2 = 'PT'.$totalTiempo.'M';

            $inicio = new DateTime($rowCabinis['horaIni']);
            if($totalTiempo > 60){
                $menosunoho2 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-2 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaFin'])));
            }else{
                $menosunoho2 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-1 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaFin'])));
            }
            $fin = new DateTime($menosunoho2);
            $fin = $fin->modify($intervarlo);

            $rangoFechas2 = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval($intervarlo2), $fin);
            foreach($rangoFechas2 as $fecha2){
                array_push($horasAlm,$fecha2->format("H:i"));
            }

        }

        // $diff = array_diff($horasAlm, $select);
        // foreach ($diff as $concat) {

        //     array_push($horasFiltradasM, $concat . ":00");
        // }
        // 

        // foreach ($minutos as $tiempo) {
        //     array_push($horasFiltradasM, $tiempo);
        //     sort($horasFiltradasM);
        // }

        
    }else{

        $ide = 'No Hay Citas';
        
        $selectCabinis = $con->query("SELECT * FROM cabinas WHERE id = '$idCabina' AND sucursal = '$sucursal' AND status = 1");
        $rowCabinis = $selectCabinis->fetch_assoc();

        if($rowCabinis['tieneComida'] == 1){

            $intervarlo = '+'.$totalTiempo.'minutes';
            $intervarlo2 = 'PT'.$totalTiempo.'M';
            
            $inicio = new DateTime($rowCabinis['horaIni']);
            $menosunoho1 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-1 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaComidaIni'])));
            $inicioComida = new DateTime($menosunoho1);
            $inicioComida = $inicioComida->modify($intervarlo);

            $rangoFechas = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval($intervarlo2), $inicioComida);
            foreach($rangoFechas as $fecha){
                array_push($horasFiltradas,$fecha->format("H:i"));
            }

            
            $finComida = new DateTime($rowCabinis['horaComidaFin']);
            $menosunoho2 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-1 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaFin'])));
            $fin = new DateTime($menosunoho2);
            $fin = $fin->modify($intervarlo);

            $rangoFechas2 = new DatePeriod($finComida, new DateInterval($intervarlo2), $fin);
            foreach($rangoFechas2 as $fecha2){
                array_push($horasFiltradas,$fecha2->format("H:i"));
            }

            // $arrays = array_combine($keys, $horasFiltradas);
            // array_push($finales, $arrays);

            // $horaIni = strftime("%k", strtotime($inicio));
            // $horaIniComi = strftime("%k", strtotime($inicioComida));
            // $horafinComi = strftime("%k", strtotime($finComida));
            // $horaFin = strftime("%k", strtotime($fin));

            //$timi = $inicio.' / '.$inicioComida.' / '.$finComida.' / '.$fin;

            // for ($i = $horaIni; $i <= $horaIniComi - 1; $i++) { 
            //     //array_push($horasFiltradasM, $i . ":00");
            //     array_push($horasFiltradas, $i);
            // }

            // for ($j = $horafinComi; $j <= $horaFin - 1; $j++) { 
            //     //array_push($horasFiltradasM, $i . ":00");
            //     array_push($horasFiltradas, $j);
            // }

            // foreach ($horasFiltradas as $antes) {
      //           //$valor = date("H:i",strtotime ( '+'.$totalTiempo.' minutes' , strtotime ($antes)));
      //           //array_push($horasOcupadas, $valor);
      //           //sort($antes);
      //           //sort($horasOcupadas);
      //           //$inicio = $horasFiltradasM;
      //           //$fin = $horasOcupadas;

      //           $option .= '<option value="">' . $antes . ':00 - ' . $antes .':'.$totalTiempo. '</option>';
      //           // foreach ($horasOcupadas as $ocupadas) {

      //            //$formato = $antes . ':00 - ' . $ocupadas;
      //            //array_push($option,$formato);
      //               //$option .=  '<option value="">' . $horasOcupadas . '</option>';
      //            //array_push($horasOcupadas, $option);
      //           // }
            
      //       }

        }else{

            $intervarlo = '+'.$totalTiempo.'minutes';
            $intervarlo2 = 'PT'.$totalTiempo.'M';

            $inicio = new DateTime($rowCabinis['horaIni']);
            $menosunoho2 = date("H:i",strtotime ( '-1 hours' , strtotime ($rowCabinis['horaFin'])));
            $fin = new DateTime($menosunoho2);
            $fin = $fin->modify($intervarlo);

            $rangoFechas2 = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval($intervarlo2), $fin);
            foreach($rangoFechas2 as $fecha2){
                array_push($horasFiltradas,$fecha2->format("H:i"));
            }

        }

    }

    echo json_encode(["Message" => "Horas Disponibles", "Status" => 1, "Tipo" => $ide, "Data" => $inarray]);
```

Comment: ¿Es un ejercicio que debemos repasar y hacerlo funcionar? o ¿nos vas a decir donde tienes el problema y el error para que podamos ayudarte?  Por favor, léete [ask] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento básico de este sitio y como hacer las preguntas correctas, gracias.

Comment: Hola que tal una disculpa, creo que no detalle ese detalle, el problema es que no logro como obtener los horarios disponible e realizado varias pruebas pero ningun me ha ayudado, la secuencia del codigo comienza después de la sentencia de if(select->num_rows > 0)

Comment: El planteamiento no es muy claro. Quizá ayudaría que pongas un pequeño ejemplo de los datos que tienes en la base de datos y de lo que esperas obtener, con un solo caso bastaría para entender. Y, te aconsejo que no hagas mezcla. Lo digo porque veo que por un lado usas `DateTime` y por otro `strtotime`. Es mejor usar solamente `DateTime` la cual puedes combinar con `DateInterval` y `DatePeriod` si fuera necesario.